# CakePHP GROUP and COUNT items returned in list

Tags: cakephp, count, group-by, cakephp-1.3

I know there are some similar quesiton like this on here but they are all about when using

```
Model->find('all');
```

But thats not what I am doing, I am doing:

```
Model->find('list');
```

Which is whats making the difference between this working and not working.

---

Given a group of Products I want to find all the brands in that group and how many of each brand.

Sounds simple enough, here is what I did:

```
$fields = array('Product.brand','COUNT(`Product`.`brand`) AS brand_count')
$brand_data = $this->Product->find('list',array(
    'fields'=>$fields,
    'conditions'=>$conditions,
    'recursive'=>0,
    'group' => 'Product.brand'
));
debug($brand_data);
```

In this I am telling it to give me an array where the Keys are `Product.brand` and the values are `COUNT(Product.brand)`

I am getting this:

```
Array
(
    [Brand A] => 
    [Brand B] => 
    [Brand C] =>  
)
```

When I am expected this:

```
Array
(
    [Brand A] => 534
    [Brand B] => 243
    [Brand C] => 172
)
```

It works if I do **all** instead of **list** though, it just gives me a much more complicated array to drill through. I am fine using **all**, I just first wanted to see if there was a reason why its not working in **list**?

Comment: I also need the same result but only getting the unique records not the counting of the duplicate records.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Brief recap**: find('list') has problems with aliased fields (and therefore aggregate functions like `COUNT()` etc.), so you should use CakePHP's 1.3 instead. For CakePHP 1.2 uses there's [a contraption](http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2008/09/04/findlist-with-three-or-combined-fields/).

**Detailed**:
Most likely problem lies in your

```
COUNT(`Product.brand`) AS brand_count
```

Because `find('list')` does

```
Set::combine($results, $lst['keyPath'], $lst['valuePath'], $lst['groupPath'])
```

on results of query, where `$lst['valuePath']` would be

```
"{n}.COUNT(`Product`.`brand`) AS brand_count"
```

while in results it would be actually `"{n}.Product.brand_count"` - doesn't line up.

Try making your COUNT() a virtual field.

I.e.:

```
//model
var $virtualFields = array(
    'brand_count' => 'COUNT(Product.brand)'
);

//controller
$fields = array('Product.brand','Product.brand_count');
```

Comment: Thanks, If I made brand_count a virtual field mapping to a COUNT function, then wouldn't that inadvertently group all my other queries as well? Maybe its better I just stick with using *all* instead of *list*

Comment: No, it would just add `COUNT(Product.brand) AS brand_count` to all queries (which will essentially returns you count of brands in this query - as you didn's supply a `GROUP BY`). So it's totally safe. :) To make it clear: `COUNT` in a query doesn't force a `GROUP BY`, it just counts all rows with non-NULL value of counted field.

Answer (score 1):

In controller in Paginator you can use like this:

```
 $itemads = $this->paginate($itemads, ['contain' => ['Departments', 'Stores'],'group'=>'upc','fields'=>array("upc_count"=>"COUNT(`upc`)")]);
```

Comment: Not working for me. I need the data with the duplicate counting.