# Sorting through paginator in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, paginator

I am fetching the records from the database & displaying as a table view., I've come across through a problem that,I'm taking the value from the db directly but displaying the count of that field.

If I wanna make sorting I need to sort on the count of the field but I dont have the count value in the db directly

For eg..

If this is my sorting through Paginator..

```
$this->Paginator->sort('user_id', 'User account');
```

I need to sort on `count(user_id)` as I am displaying the count of the `user_id`, but I was unable to do that through the paginator helper..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use virtual fields

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html

[CakePHP GROUP and COUNT items returned in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711927/cakephp-group-and-count-items-returned-in-list)

```
var $virtualFields = array(
    'user_count' => 'COUNT(user_id)'
);
```