# Cakephp, group by - count function is returning null

Tags: sql, count, null, group-by, cakephp-2.0

I have the next statement :

```
$lead_count = $this->Lead->find("list", array("conditions" => array("chosen_country_id" => $countries, "lead_type" => "Consumer"), 
                                                    "fields" => array('Lead.status', 'count(Lead.id)'),
                                                    "group" => "Lead.status"));
```

The formed query from this statement is :

```
SELECT "Lead"."status" AS "Lead__status", count("Lead"."id") 
FROM "public"."leads" AS "Lead" 
WHERE chosen_country_id IN (167, 201, 203, 39) AND "lead_type" = 'Consumer' 
GROUP BY "Lead"."status"
```

If I run this query manually on my database the result is:

```
    Lead__status         | count
-----------------------------+-------
 Contacted                   |     1
 Assigned to lead dispatcher |     1
 On call                     |     3
 Sent to Distributor         |     1
 Call attempted 1            |     1
 New                         |   241
 Mark as invalid             |     1
```

but on in my webpage the result is:

array(

```
'Contacted' => null,
'Assigned to lead dispatcher' => null,
'On call' => null,
'Sent to Distributor' => null,
'Call failed 1' => null,
'New' => null,
'Mark as invalid' => null
```

)

Any ideas why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please find your answer from this thread i think this is smiler question..

[CakePHP GROUP and COUNT items returned in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711927/cakephp-group-and-count-items-returned-in-list)